# C Dynamically Allocate and Initialize Struct Without Knowing Its Type

Tags: c, malloc, memcpy, void-pointers

I have a series of structs that all have some relatively verbose initialization logic and am trying to refactor that out into a helper function so I don't have to keep writing it over and over. Here's a condensed version:

```
struct base
{
    const int *i;
}

struct child1
{
    struct base b;

    int j;
}

struct child2
{
    struct base b;

    int k;
}

void *alloc_base_holder(const int *i, size_t size)
{
    struct base b = { i };
    void *anon = malloc(size);

    // error GD320D622: 'memcpy' forming offset [N1, N2] is out of the bounds [0, N3] of object 'b' with type 'struct base'
    return memcpy(anon, &b, size);
}

struct child1 *c1_alloc(const int *i)
{
    return (struct child1 *)alloc_base_holder(i, sizeof(struct child1));
}

struct child2 *c2_alloc(const int *i)
{
    return (struct child2 *)alloc_base_holder(i, sizeof(struct child2));
}
```

I'm trying to dynamically allocate and initialize the memory given the size of the struct and not the type, but I'm not sure how to do that.

My first thought was to initialize the `base` part that is common to all of the `child` types, and then just `memcpy` that into a `void` pointer that had been allocated to the correct `size`, but that's giving the error:

```
error GD320D622: 'memcpy' forming offset [N1, N2] is out of the bounds [0, N3] of object 'b' with type 'struct base'
```

I also had the idea to just manually set the memory of the `void` pointer (`anon`), but if that's possible, I haven't come up with the right search terms to find it.

Is this possible to do and can somebody point me in the right direction?

Edit:
I'm using gcc with C99 by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason of the warning are explained in the other answer.

I suggest always accessing the object via it's final type (`struct child1` or `struct child2`). Otherwise one may easily trigger UB due to strict aliasing rules.
Therefore it's better to have `init_base_holder()` rather than `alloc_base_holder`.

```
void init_base_holder(struct base *b, const int *i)
{
    b->i = i;
}

struct child1 *c1_alloc(const int *i)
{
    struct child1 *c = malloc(sizeof *c);
    init_base_holder(&c->b, i);
    return c;
}

struct child2 *c2_alloc(const int *i)
{
    struct child2 *c = malloc(sizeof *c);
    init_base_holder(&c->b, i);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean ALWAYS access it via it's final type or just in this scenario? Is it unsafe to do:  struct base *b = (struct base *)c1_alloc(MY_CONST_INT) ?

Comment: @Thick_propheT, the cast itself is safe. The problem is that when you have `struct child1 *c = c1_alloc(MY_CONST_INT); struct base *b = (struct base*)c;` The compiler is not obligated to notice that changes to `b->i` affects `c->b.j`.

Answer (score 1):

You get the "error" because you copy `size` bytes from the `base` structure `b`, even if `size > sizeof b` (which will go out of bounds of the `b` structure object).

I recommend that you use [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) instead, to let the allocator zero-initialize the allocated memory.

Then copy only the `base` structure itself, i.e. `sizeof b` instead:

```
memcpy(anon, &b, sizeof b);
```

Of course, you first need to make sure that `size >= sizeof b`.

Comment: The cast sets object's effective type to 'struct base'. Accessing this object as child1or child2 may trigger UB due to violation of strict aliasing rules. Am I right?

Comment: @tstanisl No you're correct. Updated my answer.

Comment: It looks that `memcpy` has similar problems. See https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6

Comment: @tstanisl out of curiosity, what does UB stand for?

Comment: @Thick_propheT [**U**ndefined **B**ehavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: @Thick_propheT, Undefined Behavior. It mean that the C standard puts no restrictions on a code generated by the compiler. Usually it results in subtle bugs that are very difficult to identify.

Answer (score 0):

You can just allocate `size` bytes for an instance of `base`.

```
struct base *b = malloc(size);
```

And then initialize the members as usual.